# Material-icons not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

Following is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.0",
    "@material/form-field": "^0.39.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "angular4-fusioncharts": "^1.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "fusioncharts": "^3.12.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  }
```

And I have tried to implement it as:

```
<mat-icon>date_range</mat-icon>
```

The icons are missing.

Comment: did you import them in your app.module?

Comment: yes i have added

Comment: check the material-module.ts file and see how it's imported in the main.ts or app.module in your case

https://stackblitz.com/angular/xnjoedalvkk?file=material-module.ts

Comment: import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';

Comment: have you add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">` in index page

Comment: @ShirishPatel ..Is that needed..because i have already done npm install

Comment: Yep, you need to add, let me add reference link in my answer so you can follow

Comment: I had forgotten to add  "../node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css" in styles in angular.cli.jjson ..thanks for the help

Comment: I removed "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1" from my dependencies and cleared it form my angular.json styles:[] section, and import sections of my styles.css. Only kept the index.html import using all different typey: 
 <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp"
    rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you missed font import in index.html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1" from my dependencies and cleared material icons form my angular.json styles:[] section, and import sections of my styles.css. The only thing required is the index.html head to correctly use the material.io names, before this some of the icons worked but others like dark_mode did not work

In index.html import using all types (outline, two+Tone,,) - required if you want to use more than just the standard set

```
<head> 
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp"
   rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```